# OData on Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, odata, wcf-data-services

I'm not sure if maybe I'm just not finding the correct information. But the OData story on windows phone 7 seems to be incomplete. I've followed the steps in this blog post:
http://dotnetspeak.com/index.php/2010/03/windows-phone-7-application-with-odata/

This generated the expected client types as described. Unfortunately, when I add the class and reference to my windows phone client app (System.Data.Services.Client.dll) and compile, I'm receiving the following error message:

```
The type or namespace name 'DataServiceQuery' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data.Services.Client' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

So am I missing something? all I need is to be able to query an odata data service. If there is another way, technique, or library, I'm open to using that.

Answer (score 2):

OData v2 was released last week ([Read the announcement here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/astoriateam/)). Chris Koenig has a very nice post summarizing the changes in [his blog post here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201204071620/http://chriskoenig.net/2010/10/30/odata-v2-and-windows-phone-7/). You need to download the latest [OData client library from Codeplex](https://web.archive.org/web/20180101022951/http://odata.codeplex.com:80/), specifically [this revision](http://odata.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/9f6b1932eb44). Chris Koenig's tutorial should point you to the right direction. Always remember to add a reference to the OData client assembly.

HTH, indyfromoz

Comment: That did the trick (mostly). I'm able to query my odata service now ... however, it's only returning the last entry in the sequence ?? I wonder if perhaps there's something obvious here that I could check, or whether I should start a new question?

Comment: Can you post the query you are using? We should be able to find out from the URL/query the select statement that is executed on the database.